# Substitute variable inside the previous declared variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

Here is template variable VAR1 that need to be updated based on the VAR2 and the order of variable is as below how can I update VAR1 without sed command

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR1="<tr>
    <th>\$VAR2</th>
  </tr>"
VAR2=test
echo $VAR2
```

Comment: Seems like an XY problem, why must they me declared in that order?

Comment: sorry, it is just a question, not a problem, just to know its possibility

Comment: Is this specifically about replacing a certain string in XML with the value of a shell variable?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Unix.stackexchange.com . Like @jesse_b said, this seems a XYProblem: you seem to ask for X (a way to implement a specific solution), but instead it's much better to state Y (what the goal is) (as often, the "right" solution is then often something completely different than the one you are trying to achieve).   What are you trying to achieve, exactly? What use cases do you have?

Comment: and I believe the last line should be :  `echo $VAR1` ? as it seems you try to modify VAR1's value with VAR2's content

Answer (score 5):

You could use `envsubst`:

(with any POSIX shell, including `bash`):

```
VAR1="<tr>
    <th>\$VAR2</th>
  </tr>"
VAR2=test

expanded_VAR1=$(
  export VAR2
  printf '%s\n' "$VAR1" |
    envsubst '$VAR2'
)
```

Or to perform all word expansions (parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion) *upon* parameter expansion, you could use `zsh` and its `e` parameter expansion flag:

```
#!/bin/zsh -
VAR1="<tr>
    <th>\$VAR2</th>
  </tr>"
VAR2=test

expanded_VAR1=${(e)VAR1}
```

In POSIX shells, you can do something similar with a `eval` and a here-document:

```
VAR1="<tr>
    <th>\$VAR2</th>
  </tr>"
VAR2=test

expanded_VAR1=$(eval "cat << EOF
$VAR1
EOF")
```

Another option with `bash` or `zsh` would be to use `printf`:

```
VAR1='<tr>
    <th>%s</th>
  </tr>'
VAR2=test

printf -v expanded_VAR1 -- "$VAR1" "$VAR2"
```

With `zsh` (but not `bash`), you can use the `%n$s` syntax (like in many `printf(3)` implementations) to refer to the `n`<sup>th</sup> argument:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
VAR1='<tr>
    <th>%1$s</th> <th>%1$s again</th> <th>%2$s</th>
  </tr>'
VAR2=test VAR3=test2

printf -v expanded_VAR1 -- "$VAR1" "$VAR2" "$VAR3"
```

Or use `zformat` to name your format directives arbitrarily (limited to single-byte characters other than `-`, `.`, NUL and decimal digits):

```
#! /bin/zsh -
VAR1='<tr>
    <th>%a</th> <th>%a again</th> <th>%b</th>
  </tr>'
VAR2=test VAR3=test2

zformat -f expanded_VAR1 "$VAR1" "a:$VAR2" "b:$VAR3"
```

With `ksh93`, you can use `%H` instead of `%s` in its `printf` for special characters in HTML to be properly encoded (like for instance for `&` to become `&amp;`), though for non-ASCII characters, it only works properly in locales using the iso8859-1 charset. `ksh93`'s `printf` doesn't support `-v`, but you can use `expanded_VAR1=${ printf... ;}`.

With the `printf`/`zformat` approaches, literal `%` characters in the template can be escaped as `%%` (and `\` as `\\` in `printf`), and with the `e`/`eval`+here-doc approaches, the `$`/`` ` ``/`\`s by prefixing them with `\`. With `envsubst`, AFAIK, the `$` cannot be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

You could use parameter expansion to replace a unique string in var1 with the value of var2:

```
var1='<tr>
    <th>unique_placeholder_var2</th>
  </tr>'
var2=test
echo "${var1/unique_placeholder_var2/"$var2"}"
```

Comment: what if we have multiple unique strings in var1 to replace, can we replace it in one command (expansion).

Comment: You could with eval but it seems awfully risky and should probably be avoided unless there are absolutely no other solutions

Comment: This method will (probably) fail if $var2 contains a "/", amongst (many) other things. In any case, OP's idea of substituting a (probably user entered?) variable content is prone to lots of abuse and weird cases... we need to know what the goal is to give the best solution

Comment: jesse: Did this work for you? When I try it, I get quotes in the output (``<th>"test"</th>``). It seems to work fine when I leave off the inner quotes so long as I keep the outer ones (i.e., ``"${var1/unique_placeholder_var2/$var2}"``). @OlivierDulac: I tried a few special characters (slash, space, quotes, parentheses, `}`, `*`) and I can't make it fail. Sure, if the user can set `var2` to `</th>something<th>`, that might lead to abuse à la “Bobby Tables”, but can you identify anything that can go wrong at the shell level?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica': yes it works for me, I don't know how the quotes are being left in for you because double quotes don't escape double quotes.

Comment: @OlivierDulac: `/` is no issue, nor is any special character that I can think of

Comment: Left in? I guess I wasn't clear (and the question isn't clear, either). When I do ``"${var1/unique_placeholder_var2/$var2}"``, I get ``…<th>test</th>…``, which (I assume) is what the OP wants.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica': When I do `"${var1/unique_placeholder_var2/"$var2"}"` I get `…<th>test</th>…`

Comment: Interesting. I'm using version 4.1.17. Perhaps Stéphane will explain this for us.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `var1` contain well formed XML:

```
var1='
<tr>
  <th>$var2</th>
</tr>
'

var2=test
```

Then you may use `xmlstarlet` to replace the value of all `th` nodes that have the literal value `$var2` with the value of the shell variable `var2` like so:

```
var1=$( printf '%s\n' "$var1" | xmlstarlet ed -u '//th[text() = "$var2"]' -v "$var2" )
```

This calls `xmlstarlet` with an XPATH query that selects all `th` nodes that we'd like to modify.  `xmlstarlet` will replace the value of these nodes with the value of the `var2` shell variable, and will write the result to standard output.

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$var1"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tr>
  <th>test</th>
</tr>
```

Note that this would correctly encode the value in `var2` for inclusion into your XML document:

```
$ var1='
<tr>
  <th>$var2</th>
</tr>
'
$ var2='HÉLLO :->'
$ var1=$( printf '%s\n' "$var1" | xmlstarlet ed -u '//th[text() = "$var2"]' -v "$var2" )
$ printf '%s\n' "$var1"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tr>
  <th>H&#xC9;LLO :-&gt;</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

A general method to substitute variables in a template:

- use bash regular expressions to capture the variable name (due to greedy matching, this matches variable names from right to left
- use variable indirection to get the variable value
- remove the matched varname from the input string to avoid infinite loop (this destroys the original string, back it up if you need it further)

Demonstrating

1. set the template and (not all) the variables to be substituted

   ```bsh
   VAR1="<tr>
       <th>\$VAR2</th>
       <th>\$VAR3</th>
     </tr>"
   VAR2=test
   unset VAR3
   ```
2. perform the substitutions

   ```bsh
   result=""
   while [[ $VAR1 =~ (.*)\$([[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*)(.*) ]]; do
       varname=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
       [[ -v $varname ]] && replacement=${!varname} || replacement="\$${varname}"
       result="${replacement}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${result}"
       VAR1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
   done
   result="${VAR1}${result}"
   declare -p result
   ```
3. examine the result

   ```
   declare -- result="<tr>
       <th>test</th>
       <th>\$VAR3</th>
   </tr>"
   ```

This requires bash version 4.3+ for the `-v` operator.

Comment: Would this still do the right thing if there are overlap in variable names inside the template, such as `VAR2` and `VAR23`, and both of those variable happened to exist?

Comment: Because of regex greediness it will use the longest name. Presumably this is what you mean by "the right thing"

Comment: It could be made more robust by requiring braces around the varnames in the template

Comment: Yes, or by also matching the `<` in the tag after the variable?

Comment: I wouldn't assume the variable is the only content of a tag. Could be an attribute value. Regardless, the regex pattern should only match a variable identifier.